# Ordinary Differential Equation Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $$g$$ and $$ h$$ be solutions of the second-order linear differential equation

$$a(x)y'' +b(x)y' + c(x)y = 0$$

on an interval where a(x) is never
zero.

Show that the Wronskian W of g and h satisfies
$$a(x)W'(x) + b(x)W(x) = 0$$

Now $$W(x) = gh' - hg$$
and
$$W'(x) = h''g - g''h$$
Then I get,
$$a(x)W'(x) + b(x)W(x) = g(a(x)h'' + b(x)h') - h(a(x)g'' + b(x)g')$$
To get this expression to equal 0 I need to show $$c(x) = 0$$ so that the h and g satisfy the ODE to bring 0 but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't used the fact that $h$ and $g$ satisfy the given ODE. This gives you the following equalities:

$$
\begin{align*}
a(x)h'' + b(x)h' &= -c(x)h \\
a(x)g'' + b(x)g' &= -c(x)g.
\end{align*}
$$

Substituting into your last equation,
$$
\begin{align*}
a(x)W'(x) + b(x)W(x) &= g(-c(x)h) - h(-c(x)g) \\
&= c(x)[-gh + hg] \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: All good, thanks.